# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi keeps disconnecting with RT3290

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, internet, ralink

It's been almost one month and the internet has let me down, I cannot find a solution to this issue.

My WiFi will intermittently disconnect between 30 seconds - 30 minutes. It will often get into a fit of continuously disconnecting if I try to reconnect it.

The issue persists on WPA2-Enterprise (auth: PEAP, inner auth: MSCHAPv2), standard WPA/WPA2, and open internet.

Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b354 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd UVC 1.00 device HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 06)
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
05:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
05:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
07:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Also even when the internet is working, I usually lose ~15% of packets, whereas on my Windows partition I lose <1% after 30 minutes of pinging. I'm not sure if this is related or not.

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: Posted it. I read up on that setting a little bit and changed it to 2 while I do some testing. If I don't respond back, assume it is still 3.

Comment: Update: No change seen by switching from 3 to 2. I changed it back to 3.

Comment: This is not the answer most will want to hear, but between myself, the internet, and my massive group computer science/engineering friends, no one could figure this out.
I then bought a new wireless card and it works perfectly.
The card I bought:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IOS19E6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1